# How to find image on screen

Tags: command-line, image-processing

How to find coordinates of image file on screen, if it present on screen, from command line?
Its needed for bot what clicking button in firefox-flash, button have different coordinates from time to time. I have image of that button and looking for a way to find its coordinates. Then I click it with `xdotool`.
I have google for it without any success.

Answer (score 1):

I can't really tell from your description if it's what you really want...

But `xev` will give you the coordinates of the position of your mouse on the designated popup window.

You can pass a specific window id to xev like `xev -id 0x3200002` and it will provide the same information for the window that you tell it to watch...

You can get the window id for any window on your screen by using `xwininfo` and selecting the window you want to watch... xwininfo also provides a lot of info about the windows that you may find useful for your problem....

There may be some parameters that you can pass to those commands to help you get what you want.... Check their man pages.

Comment: Thanks, but that not what Im looking for